# Doubts how to design a card game in DDD

Tags: domain-driven-design

I was thinking how to design a simple cards game, like poker, in a DDD way, but I am not sure about some points.

Basically what I want is this, but I will try to simplify the problems that I have.

- I have a match in which I can add players.
- A match is played in 10 rounds.
- Each player play in the round in its turn (for simplify, one turn per round). In this turn it can request card, throw card, bet and so on.
- A match is attended by an arbitrator, that is who shuffle the cards, tell when a player starts its turn and finish it, give the cards to the player... etc.
- In each round, I want to know the time that a player spend in its turn. And also I want to know the total time of a round in the match.

I will expose the model that I would think and later i will tell my doubts.

Class match:

```
    Class Match
    {
        long Id;
        DateTime Date;
        string Description;
        List<Player> Players;
        List<Round> Rounds;


        public void Start() {}
        public void Finish() {}
        .....
    }

Class Player()
{
    long Id;
    string Name;
    List<Round> Round;


    public void StartTurn() {}
    public void FinishTurn() {}
    public void Bet() {}
    public void RequestCard() {}
    public void ThrowCard() {}
    public void Bet() {}
    .....
}

Class Round
{
    long Id;
    long TimeInSeconds;


    public StartCountingTime() {}
    public StopCountingTime() {}
}


class Arbitrator()
{
    public void shuffle() {}
    public void AsignTurnToPlayer() {}
    public void GiveCardToPlayer() {}
    public void StartGame() {}
    public void FinishGame() {}
    ....
}
```

I think this solution because in this way, when a player gets the turn, they can call the method StartCountingTime() in the Round entity and call StopCountingTime() when they finishes they turn. It is easy, but I am not sure if the player should have the responsability to count the time, the player should play only.

Then I was thinking since the Arbitrator decides when the player starts and stops its turn, it could manage the time in the rounds. But in this case, where should I declare the Round objects for the players? And thinking again, is the Arbitrator entity the responsible for controlling the time, or only responsible for making players follow the rules and coordinate the match?

My main problem is with control of the time spending in the rounds. How to handle it, where to declare the Round objects and related it with the Match and with the Players.

And the second doubt is with the Match entity, really in my code I declare two methods to start and stop the game, but this perhaps it is more a responsibility of the Arbitrator than the game, but if the Match entity has not methods, it would be an anemic object, but really I need this object to can store the Id, the description and to know the players that plays in the match.

So in summary, my main question is who has the responsibility to control the time in the rounds. And the second question is whether the Match entity could be seen as an anemic entity or if it is correct in this way.

Comment: In the textual description, you literally said that it it the Abitrator's job, so what's wrong with that?  You don't yet have the state to keep the time per player per round.  Find a home for that state, probably in the `Round`.

Comment: It is not clear the purpose for the Player having a list of Rounds, what if the Player is in several Matches, is this a list of all Rounds or specific to some current globally-known Match?

Comment: DDD is mostly about aggregates, bounded contexts, and an "ubiquitous language."  Do you have those?  Read [this](https://medium.com/vx-company/domain-driven-design-in-a-nutshell-aadb05f834ce).

Comment: @ErikEidt A player can play many rounds in different matches, yes, but I I only want to know the time of a player in a round. From a database point of view it would be something like this: Round(IdRound, IdMatch, IdPlayer, time).

Comment: @RobertHarvey Well, I am starting to learn about DDD and I was thinking in this basic example. I was considerating the Game a my context, the player, the match and the rounds as entities and also the behaviour about them. For simplify, the Arbitrator asigns the turn to a player, then the player can request card, throw, bet... al this is notify and attended by the arbitrator. When arbitrator decides its turn is finished, it gives the turn to the next player... and so. Accoding with the example of the cab in the link, I think I have the basic concepts. But I could be wrong, sure.

Comment: @ÁlvaroGarcía: your question is fine, however, I would not call this DDD - only "domain-modeling" , that would probably avoid the confusion caused to some people here, and less distracting. Take Ewan's answer, for example - I am under the impression the fact you tagged your question DDD made him completely ignore what you really asked for.

Comment: ... though DDD's primary goal is to create domain models, it contains a lot more techniques which are completely irrelevant for your case. "domain model" however is a pattern, which for many people just means "OO design", and that's a little bit older than DDD.

Comment: About your question's content, I don't understand some things here. Isn't this game played by a human who controls the game by some user interface and makes the decisions about requesting or throwing a card or betting? Or by some AI? Or shall the player class contain the code for the AI? Whatever the situation is, to me it makes usually not much sense to let an Arbitrator call the players methods on requesting or throwing a card, shouldn't that be someone else's responsibility?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

I think you've chosen a bad example for DDD.

Obviously you haven't gone into all the details, but it looks like you only have the one Domain, one stakeholder, one thread in memory application, well understood rules etc

You app can be designed by one person on a bit of paper, written in an OOP or imperative style, be finished and bug free and never need any updates.

DDD is trying to solve the issues that occur where you have multiple stakeholders, multiple applications, poorly understood rules, people talking about the same thing but calling it different things, people talking about different things but calling it the same thing. etc etc

If you want to consider DDD aspects, write your app however you like and then add the following requirements

- Marketing : when a player hasn't bet in 30 days I want to send them an email
- Accounts : don't let a player bet more than their credit limit
- Regulatory : players from the US can only bet on games where the server is in Las Vegas

Now you have to think about all these other systems that work with the game and how you are going to get them all to fit together and implement these requirements which don't have anything to do with each other or actually playing the game.

While you are doing that, pretend that you get a constant stream of these style of request from all sorts of departments.

Comment: Thanks for the comments. Yes, perhaps it is a very small application that I can develop faster and in simplier way without DDD, but sometimes the examples that can be found are big or complex and for a first time can be a bit complicated, so it is why I would like to try to think a very small example and try to think in a DDD away. I appreciate your comments so much, and the suggestions.

Comment: "I appreciate your comments so much"... upvotes 0 :(